# Accessing drive shared on home network on Qubes

Tags: qubes-os

I just set up Qubes and am trying to access a hard drive that I'm sharing from a Windows PC in my home network but am unable to locate the drive. Is this possible? how do I go about doing this? Is it possible to use a NAS with Qubes and would that be more convenient?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the VM you're in uses the Firewall VM for networking (and not sys-whonix) to be inside your local network. Then you should be able to mount samba (=> Windows) shares just as usual in Linux.

Have a look at the `cifs-utils` package:

- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/mounting_an_smb_share
- https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-samba-mounting.html